# Нумерация одинаковых строк без изменения их порядка в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

Массив строк `std::string str[] = {"строка", "01строка", "09строка", "04строка", "03строка", "01строка", "09строка", "05строка", "03строка", "строка", "01строка", "06строка", "03строка", "06строка", "09строка", "строка", "01строка", "05строка", "строка", "04строка", "строка", "09строка"};`Мне нужно пронумеровать одинаковые строки - в конец строки прибавить ее номер в формате "_00n" (например, строка_001, строка_002, 01строка_001, 01строка_002 и т.д.). При этом пронумерованная строка должна быть записана в другой массив на то же место, что и в исходном массиве (т.е. строка_001 на 1 место, строка_002 на 10 место и т.д.). Мне не удалось придумать алгоритм решения этой задачи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм решения этой задачи средствами C++.

Comment: Если в массиве есть "уникальная строка", её надо переделывать в "уникальная строка_001"? Или она должна остаться как есть?

Comment: правила плохие, неполные. Не описан случай, если при добавлении номера "_00n" получившаяся строка будет идентична другой оригинальной строке. Результат будет разный в зависимости от порядков обработки строк. Сначала или с конца. *Скорее всего в правилах должно быть условие, что в строках нельзя использовать символ `'_'`.* Без полного описания задачи со всеми тонкостями может быть совет вам будет неправильным.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, можно придумать решение которое будет работать нормально даже в описанной вам ситуации (хотя бы изготовить копию массива). Можно специально указать что есть такое требование.

Answer (score 1):

Раз еще и в такой же массив...

Берете очередной элемент, смотрите — пуст ли элемент во втором массиве. Если нет — элемент уже обработан, переходите к следующему. Если да — проходите весь первый массив в поисках такого же, добавляя элементы во второй массив в соответствующие места с соответствующими окончаниями.

O(n^2), если сортировать — быстрее (O(n log n)), но тогда надо держать еще массив (O(n)) с исходными позициями, раз они так важны...

Comment: Ещё словарь можно завести со счётчиками.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, еще эффективнее, если словарь полагать O(1). Но по памяти может оказаться неэффективно, если все строки различны. Но для строк может оказаться не только большая память, но и большая константа при хешировании...